# C# textbox deletion question

Tags: c#, textbox

I am working on a project that I use textbox as telnet terminal. 
The terminal has "->" as the command prompt in the textbox.
Is there a way to disable the delete or backspace once it reach the "->" prompt?

I don't want to delete the command prompt.

Thanks

Comment: Set e.SuppressKeyPress = true in the KeyDown event handler.  Are you handling the arrow keys?

Comment: I am not handling the arrow keys now.

Answer (score 4):

Dave is right.

The best way to do this is to make a label on the left side of the textbox that says `->`.
You can remove the textbox's border and put them both in a white (or non-white) box to make it look real.

This will be much easier for you to develop and maintain, and will also be more user-friendly.  (For example, the Home key will behave better)

Comment: +1 - Apart from the home key, also consider mouse interaction, such as selecting all text and then pasting in something from the clipboard and other such actions.

Comment: Why is right side? Isn't the prompt always show up at the beginning of a line which is on the left side?

We also need to update the position of the Label as more data coming in from telnet socket?

Comment: I meant the left side; sorry.  Do you have a single multi-line textbox that includes both the prompt and the incoming data?

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

1. Make the prompt ("->") an image or label, instead of being part of the textbox.
2. If it's a web app, handle the textchanged event in javascript and cancel the textchanged if it represents a deletion of the prompt.  If its not a web app, do the same thing in c# rather than JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could always make sure that when deleting, the index of the character you're deleting is > 1 (since -> would occupy positions 0  & 1)

Comment: this will have problems if someone adds characters before the prompt

Comment: True, I guess I was assuming that no characters would be allowed there. The best choice is to make a label.

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive example, but you should be able to figure it out from here.  You can peak at the keydown event and cancel it, when desired.

```
private void testTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && testTextBox.SelectionStart == 2)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many corner cases to take care of here that I hardly think it's worth the effort. Some examples: CTRL+A followed by DEL, right-click -> Select All, then right-click -> Delete, the cut/paste commands, and so on. The list can be made quite long...